# Is it ok if CPU temp jumps around?

Tags: cpu, fan, temperature, cpu-cooler, water-cooling

I had a Coolermaster Hyper 212 EVO and my CPU temp was around 36-45 idle so I bought a Corsair Hydro 105 because someone suggested it to me, and my temps have gone to 29-50.
My question is, is it normal for the temp to jump around so much when the computer is just idle? By idle I mean I don't have anything open, or just one browser. If it's jumping up and down ten-fifteen degrees does that mean I installed the fan wrong?

Comment: Define what "ok" means exactly to you, the word "ok", is sort of subjective.  What unit of measurement are you using exactly?  When you have the higher "idle" temperatures, what is your CPU usage at exactly, provide specifics.  Update your question to provide this information.

Comment: You might also find that the system is not as idle as you think. I've often had to restart my browser - reducing the number of open tabs/windows does not fix it. Why not monitor processes and CPU clock speeds while the system is idle to work out if it is actually idle?

Answer (score 3):

If the temperature is as low as 29c, it sounds like it was installed properly and is capable of cooling your CPU.

The higher than normal temp of 50c could be an indication that your radiator fans are not turning on quick enough. Is there a way to configure your radiator fans to turn on at a lower temp?

I would also see the results of testing with a high load on your CPU using a program like prime95. https://www.mersenne.org/download/

Comment: I did that in Bios and now it seems pretty steady, thanks. :D